# Statistical test for multiple time measures, categorical dependent variable, percentages

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, explanatory-models

What test would fit for the following research question?

Data: measured in 5 subsequent years, is within design

Dependent variable = A is categorical and ordinal

Independent variables = B, C, D and E, where D and E are categorical and ordinal and B and C are both numerical.

I would like to test whether a change in B or a change in C over two or multiple time measurements is more responsible for a change in A.

Hypothesis = when B increases by x, this gives a stronger rise in A than when C increases by x. Hereby controlling on D and E and keeping these variables constant so that they don't create noise.

First I thought about a logistic regression, and that the bèta-coefficients can explain whether the effect of B or C is stronger on A. However, I would like to compare 2 years with each other. So how can this be done?